# Android - Clarification of X,Y Coordinates and Positioning ImageView Inside RelativeLayout

Tags: java, c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I'm trying to determine how X, Y coordinates work in Android.

If I have an ImageView inside of a RelativeLayout, are the X, Y coordinates the left and top edge of the ImageView, or the center?

Also, it is best to use SetX() and SetY() to change the position of the ImageView inside a RelativeLayout, or Top and Left?

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false" />
```

Comment: where do you wanna set the X and Y in your code?

Comment: @Shubhank The ImageView changes position throughout the activity via animation. When I setx (0) for the ImageView, there is a gap between the RelativeLayout parent and the image displayed in the ImageView. This makes me think I've misunderstood how x, y coordinates work.

Answer (score 0):

`setX()`, `setY()`, `setLeft()`, `setRight()` are methods on Android View class and are hence inherited by ImageView.

According to the Android documentation for setX,

```
void setX (float x)
```

Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels. This is equivalent to setting the translationX property to be the difference between the x value passed in and the current left property.

It means that the ImageView(or rather the View) will be added to its parent(a ViewGroup) with an offset of X from the default position where view would have been placed.

X and Y properties are always calculated from top and left.

To position an ImageView within a relativelayout, it is best to use,

```
layout_alignParentTop
layout_alignParentLeft
layout_alignParentRight
layout_alignParentBottom
layout_centerInParent
```

coupled with options of margins like

```
layout_marginLeft="10dp"
layout_marginRight="10dp"
layout_marginTop="10dp"
layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

Comment: What about for animation? I want the ImageView to be off the screen and appear from the left edge, then disappear. Does it still make sense to use margins to show/hide the ImageView using ObjectAnimator?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set Margins using layout params:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
Button button1;
button1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also you can add for rules how one view depends on another, like that 
`params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);`

Comment: Is it best to use this method when animating an ImageView? I basically want to show an ImageView from the left edge of the screen (starting off screen and appearing from the left)?

Comment: Use ViewFlipper https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9i-5iqLEsY. It is the easiest way

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. The animation I'm working on requires more customization, not just flipping through images like that.

Comment: Use yourview.animete()